long int from string to hex array in c
I'm trying to take in a decimal number in as a string so "4000" say, and turn that into a usable Hex value. 4000 in Hex is FA0. This obviously doesn't work for a hex array looking like;
uint8_t hex_array[6] = {0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc ...}

My decimal string ranges from 0-8916 which is fine when the int isn't too long...
What I've done so far is:
int val = (int)strtol(str_input, (char **)NULL, 10);
sprintf(ui8_hex,"%x",val);
for(int m = 0; m < 2; m++){
    sscanf(&ui8_hex[m], "%2hhx", &output[m+2]);
    printf("0x%02x ",output[m+2]);
}

problem is that what I get in output[2] and output[3] is '0xfa' '0xa0' respectively. when what I'm wanting is output[2]=0x0f output[3]=0xa0
any help is much appreciated!

In the sprintf call, change %x to %04x to always produce four hexadecimal digits. That said, this is terribly inefficient all around. Once you have the value in an int, you can put its high bits in output[2] with output[2] = val >> 8; and its low bits in output[3] with output[3] = val;, presuming the elements of output are uint8_t.

What are you trying to do exactly? I feel that this is another instance of a common mistake: thinking that numbers are decimals or hexadecimals. They are not. They are just numbers (well, the hardware uses voltage levels to encode binary values, but that is an hardware implementation problem). Strings, for human interaction, are decimal or hex. Numbers are not. So if what you want is the bytes of the internal representation of your int do some ugly ((uint8_t *)(&val))[i] thing (with more precaution than that) and you'll have it (including the endian order). If you just want 256-base

(...) representation of your number (that you are free to display in base16 if you want, later, when you'll print in), just val/256, val%256. But there is really no reason to create a human representation of a string in hexadecimal, just to reparse it the next line. If there is no human between your sprintf(..."%x") and your sscanf(..."%x"), then you are doing something wrong. That would be like using a TTS library to read those number out loud in an audio file, and then another STT library to try to recognize the number uttered in the audiofile...

(Of course, my last example is a caricature. But it has the same problem: translate the number into a human representation, and then ask the machine to understand the human representation...)

I believe he is asking about converting a decimal coded string into a number string length can be any. It is not a trivial task if the number will not fit into the largest integer.

@EricPostpischil what abaut "40000000000000000000000000000" ? I think he wants to sort out not easy problem

@gulpr: There is no “40000000000000000000000000000” mentioned in the post.

Thanks all for the help.
I've implemented the solution from Eric(you're right in your assumption) and it's worked for what I asked.
However, another solution that I've done since is by altering my input and lowering it's overall resolution from 12bit to 8bit. it's not the best, but for how the code is used, it works.
int map12bit(int value) { return (int)((uint32_t)(value * 8192) / 255); }
for clarity how this is used, it's being translated from JSON string to hex essentially where the hex is needed for the next transport layer :)
Thanks again!
